# How to display json_encode value in html?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am very new to ajax and json stuff. Here is jQuery:

```
$('#myHref').change(function(){     
    $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
    {  
        data = JSON.parse(data); 
        $( '#detail' ).val(data.a);
        $( '#sector' ).val(data.b);
        $( '#unit' ).val(data.c);   
    });
});
```

In `get_projectName.php`

```
 $a=5;$b=10;$c=15;
 json_encode(array(
                   'a' => $project_code,
                   'b' => $b,
                   'c' => $c
                  ));
```

I want to display value of

> $a, $b and $c

In div

[image]

> detail, sector and unit

But I cannot display them.

Comment: undefined variable `$project_code`

Comment: Are you sure that #detail, #sector, #unit are input tags??

Comment: @AjuJohn they are not input tags but they are 3 different divs

Comment: @aldrin27 no it donot works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing printing like `echo`. Your PHP should be:

```
$a=5;$b=10;$c=15;
echo json_encode(array(
    'a' => $a,
    'b' => $b,
    'c' => $c
    ));
```

JQuery:

```
$.get('1.php',{id:value},function(data)
    {  data = JSON.parse(data); 
      $( '#detail' ).html(data.a);
      $( '#sector' ).html(data.b);
      $( '#unit' ).html(data.c);  
    });
```

Comment: echo will display `{"a":5,"b":10,"c":15}` but i need  value of a, b and c in 3 different divs individually

Comment: @yank Have you tried it? It should work. But you should use `html` / `text` in jquery if it is a div

Comment: @yank You have used `id:value` but have you initialized `value` variable? Atleast you need to provide the entire related code so we could know your concept. But for now, `value` is empty

Comment: yes, i did bt I didnot mention in question because it is not related to my question. actually `id:value` will determine the row in database and set values `$a $b and $c`. here I only ask by initialize their values to minimize the code.

Comment: @yank then this should work.. and its working.. Check your console for any errors

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you've managed to get the PHP to echo the results in JSON format and you're pulling this through to the page with the DIV via Ajax.

You'll want to:

1) Download the entire JSON response

2) Parse the response to split the three answers

3) Display the answers individually in the divs

```
//Step 1: Download the entire JSON response
$.get( "get_projectName.php", function( data ) {

  //Step 2: Parse the response
  result = JSON.parse(data);

  //Step 3: Load the responses into each div
  $( '#detail' ).html( result['a']);
  $( '#sector' ).html( result['b']);
  $( '#unit' ).html( result['c']);
});
```

If the "Detail", "Sector" and "Unit" elements are inputs and not divs, use .val instead of .html

If you need any more info, don't hesitate to let me know! :)